# How To Set Window Title Properties?

Tags: avaloniaui

Most important, how can I set the `FontFamily` of the window title? I'm trying

```
<Window ...
                 FontFamily = "EngraversGothic BT"
/>
```

This does not work.

If I wanted to remove the title bar altogether, I don't have the Properties tab from which to work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure FontFamily is used for changing the font of the title bar.
As per [API Documentation](http://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Controls/Window/)

[image: documentation screenshot]

For removing the title bar set
`HasSystemDecorations ="False"` for window.

Comment: If you want to change the `TitleBar` font in WPF, you would change the `FontFamily` property. The description is exactly fitting for changing the Window's control (the `TitleBar`) font. Thanks for the tip to remove the `TitleBar` control.